# linear programming, how to define multiple variables have same value?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ampl, excel-solver

I am trying to have a constraint in my linear programming. I have 3 factories, and each factory has 3 production lines. I have to make sure that in a factory, all the production lines should work for equal number of hours. and max number of hours they can run is h hours.

The variables are t(1,1), t(1,2), t(1,3), t(2,1), t(2,2), t(2,3), t(3,1), t(3,2), t(3,3).

The parameter is h.

The constraints I want are

t(1,1)=t(1,2)=t(1,3)t(2,1)=t(2,2)=t(2,3)t(3,1)=t(3,2)=t(3,3) Can someone explain how to write theses constraints in AMPL, and also in excel solver.

Thank You

Comment: Replace all of them with 1 variable should do the trick...?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://or.stackexchange.com/